# How to manipulate values of a dataframe without depending on the column name

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has columns like below:

```
MultiIndex([('Longitude', 'Field1'),
            ('Latitude', 'Field1'),
            ('Name with Name Text', 'Field1'),
            ('Name with Name Text', 'Field2'),
            ('IsPresent', 'Field1')],)
```

A csv example of this would be

[image]

I want to iterate through each row in the data and for each value of field I want to replace certain characters, if they exist. For example, replace `'X'` with `'Y'`. But I don't want to depend on the column name as it can change. I want to iterate over each value and strip the character. Below iteration has field names so can't use it.

```
for i, j in df1.iterrows():
    print(j['Name with Name Text']['Field1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can of course iterate row by row as described in the comment above, you can also try to find a function that does what you want on the entire column "at once".

For example, replace all "Y" to "Z" in column "col1"

```
    df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("Y", "Z"))
```

Comment: Is it possible without the column name?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to reference the column by index, or would you like to perform the operation on the entire dataframe?

Comment: entire dataframe as column names can change so don't want to be dependent on column names.

Comment: Try this for column index 2: `df.loc[:,2]'